# Improving the efficiency of a regex

Tags: python, regex

Given a string such as this:

```
upstream-status=502; upstream-scheme=http; upstream-host=dfsdf-dsfsd88.dsfsdf99.sdfsdf.dfdf.in.sdfsf; upstream-url=%2FWebObjects%2Fdsdf.woa;
```

The regex that I wrote for matching and extracting the upstream-host is:

```
upstream-host=(?P<hostname>\S+(?=;))*
```

The `?P<hostname>` allows me to create a named group.

The `\S+` matches the actual hostname.

The `?=;` says don't include the `;` in the named group.

The last `*` says I don't care what comes after.

I have a nagging feeling that there is a better way to write this regex.

Comment: *"The last `*` says I don't care what comes after."* - no, it says that the group can be repeated 0 or more times.

Comment: Is there an actual performance issue, or is this a premature optimization?

Comment: No performance issue, it's just a nagging feeling. This could be the best way. Just thought I would ask if anything stood out.

Comment: 0x5453, you are right, thanks for pointing that out. I don't think I need the *, going to remove it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can omit the lookahead and match the `;` outside of the group, as the `\S+` first captures all non whitespace chars and then you also match the last `;` instead of asserting it.

Also, you can omit the quantifier `*` from the group, as repeating it zero or more times it can also match an empty string.

```
upstream-host=(?P<hostname>\S+);
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/n6asMb/1/)